# Custom memory allocator design

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management

I have memory allocator which allocates memory for an object and calls its constructor with any given arguments, see below.

```
    // 0 args to constructor
    template <class T>
    inline T* AllocateObject() { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(); }

    // 1 args to constructor
    template <class T, typename arg0>
    inline T* AllocateObject(const arg0& a0) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(a0); }

    template <class T, typename arg0>
    inline T* AllocateObject(arg0& a0) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(a0); }

    // 2 args to constructor
    template <class T, typename arg0, typename arg1>
    inline T* AllocateObject(arg0& a0, arg1& a1) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(a0,a1); }

    template <class T, typename arg0, typename arg1>
    inline T* AllocateObject(const arg0& a0, arg1& a1) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(a0,a1); }

    template <class T, typename arg0, typename arg1>
    inline T* AllocateObject(arg0& a0, const arg1& a1) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(a0,a1); }

    template <class T, typename arg0, typename arg1>
    inline T* AllocateObject(const arg0& a0, const arg1& a1) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T))) T(a0,a1); }

    //.........
```

As you can see the number of calls grows with quite rapidly with the number of arguments. I have to alternate with 'const' and 'non-const' for each argument to make sure it plays fine with any argument I pass. (specifically, to be able to pass by references aswell as pass by value)

Is there any better way to perform the same task than to repeat this scheme? Basically I am looking at something like 8-10 arguments max and its just not very feasible I feel.

Thanks

Comment: If you never change the arguments, just use `const type &` to handle all 4 versions at once.

Comment: Is C++11 an option for you? It contains updates to the language very specific for this exact problem. EDIT: Well you're using `alignof` so shame on me for not reading more carefully. :) FireRain's answer is what I was alluding to.

Comment: C++11 is Not an option unfortunately

Comment: can you show an example chris?

Comment: also - how would that work if the c onstructor of the object might change the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a template solution, but a variable arguments `#define` could help you out of this problem.
The exact format depends on your compiler, but in MSVC it would look like this:

```
#define ALLOCATE_OBJECT(TYPE, ...) \
    ( new( InternalAllocate(sizeof(TYPE), alignof(TYPE)) ) TYPE(__VA_ARGS__) )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variadic template.

```
template <class T, class... Args>
inline T* AllocateObject(Args&&... args) {
    return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T)))
               T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The `std::forward` call will preserve any references and `const`ness.

---

Note that this requires C++11. Most recent compilers already support variadic templates (I am unsure about Microsoft’s, though).

Comment: And if you need to enforce a maximum number of arguments, `static_cast` combined with `sizeof args...` will do the trick nicely.

Comment: Too bad there really isn't any compiler that really supports it yet.  (a very new version of gcc does a bit I think)

Comment: @BobFincheimer, I've been using variadic templates on GCC for a while now. Wasn't it way back at 4.6.1?

Comment: @BobFincheimer clang and gcc supports if fully

Comment: @BobFincheimer GCC and clang support variadic templates. I am only unsure about MSVC, which did have trouble with it. That may be fixed by now, but I don’t use Windows.

Comment: @FireRain, VS11 still doesn't support them.

Comment: I stand corrected, as long as your shop is running GCC 4.6.1 (June 17, 2011) or higher, you should be good.  I know for a fact VC++ is not yet there.

Comment: @chris `static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= MAX_ARGS, "");` will do.

Comment: @BobFincheimer, Wow, it was actually back in GCC 4.3. I just looked.

Comment: @FireRain, Indeed. Thanks for the syntax correction :p An error message would be more user-friendly, though :)